# Why is Service killed and started again after 30 plus minutes?

Tags: android, service

The app is for opening the screen when the ASUS 10" tablet is rotated from a flat, horizontal position to a vertical position.  It starts a Service using the startService() method.  The service starts a broadcast receiver for screen on and off.  The receiver uses an intent to pass the screen change event to the service.
When the screen goes off, a Sensor for orientation is started. When one of the x,y,z values changes indicating vertical, the screen is turned on.

The problem is, the process is stopped and started again some time after 30 minutes.  The onDestroy() method is not called.  The started service doesn't have the sensor started so it needs to restart the sensor service for the app to continue to work.
I have a workaround for the app by having it start the sensor if the onStartCommand() method is called with a null intent and the screen is off.

I haven't added the notification code yet.  Will that fix the problem?

My tablet has a dodgy power switch that I'd rather not use too much.  I installed the Shake program but it takes a lot of battery.  So far my code doesn't show in the battery usage list.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things a can think of:

First, you are accidently calling startService. This wil execute the onstartComand even if your service is already running. This might reset some values.

Second, your device is low on ram and the os kills your service in order to free some ram. When there is more ram, the os will start your service if it is sticky.

Thrid, there is an uncaught exception, causing your services to crash.

Keep in mind that the onDestroy method is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: My workaround for the app by having it start the sensor if the onStartCommand() method is called with a null intent and the screen is off seems to work.  Do you have any suggestions for saving the service's state across the kill and restart?

Comment: I sugest using a boolean=false in your service. set to true in onstart if false. Before changing any values it must be true.

Comment: When the service is restarted, the class variables are given default values (I assume a new instance of the class is created). Otherwise it wouldn't be  problem saving state.